# AFNetworking JSON to UITableView - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, afnetworking

I'm working on my first app and starting to bang my head against the wall. I created a C# web API that spits out simple JSON. I'm using AFNetworking and getting a valid response (I believe) and now I want to take this JSON object and turn it into a UITable. Here's the code.

This is on my view did load.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"SMP" accessGroup:nil];
    NSString *password = [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
    NSString *username = [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];

    [[APIClient sharedManager] setUsername:username andPassword:password];

    [[APIClient sharedManager] getPath:@"/api/leads_calls/?$top=5&$orderby=CallStart%20desc"parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        self.leads_dict = responseObject;
        self.leads_calls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self.leads_calls addObject:self.leads_dict];

        NSLog(@"%@", self.leads_calls);

        [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // error stuff here
    }];
}
```

I'm able to breakpoint inside the following code, and then an exception is thrown:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (self.leads_calls > nil) {
         // Here is where I get the exception
         cell.textLabel.text = [[self.leads_calls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"CallerName"];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And finally, my array at time of the exception looks like this:

```
2013-06-06 14:32:11.372 SMP[39846:c07] (
        (
        {
            CallEnd = "2013-06-06T12:20:26";
            CallStart = "2013-06-06T12:11:56";
            CallerName = "xx & xx";
            CallerNo = xxxxxxxxxx;
            Handled = 0;
            ID = 1134514;
        },
        {
            CallEnd = "2013-06-06T11:36:41";
            CallStart = "2013-06-06T11:07:43";
            CallerName = "Las xx    NV";
            CallerNo = xxxxxxxxxx;
            Handled = 0;
            ID = 1134333;
        },
        {
            CallEnd = "2013-06-04T13:09:00";
            CallStart = "2013-06-04T12:58:36";
            CallerName = "xx LAW FI";
            CallerNo = xxxxxxxxxx;
            Handled = 0;
            ID = 1129882;
        },
                {
            CallEnd = "2013-06-03T16:43:31";
            CallStart = "2013-06-03T16:32:32";
            CallerName = "xx xx";
            CallerNo = xxxxxxxxxx;
            Handled = 0;
            ID = 1127940;
        },
                {
            CallEnd = "2013-06-03T07:46:16";
            CallStart = "2013-06-03T07:44:23";
            CallerName = "xx x";
            CallerNo = xxxxxxxxxx;
            Handled = 0;
            ID = 1125648;
        }
    )
)
```

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that cell.textLabel.text is getting a value it doesn't expect, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: what's the crash? does '[self.leads_calls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]' work and what does it return?

Comment: [__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x758fb60

Comment: So what's the output of NSLog(@"%@", self.leads_calls); ?

Comment: It's exactly what's written above in the last code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have just one NSDictionary object in your array rather than many.

The `text` property you are trying to set on the `UILabel` surely isn't an `NSString` as it's meant to be either.

What is the class of the `responseObject`?

Find out with:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [responseObject class]);
```

or in the debugger:

```
po [responseObject class]
```

Also:

`self.leads_calls > nil` is not a common convention in Objective-C. `self.leads_calls.count > 0` is better

**EDIT**

ok, scrap the dictionary `leads_dict` and do `self.leads_calls = responseObject`

then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.leads_calls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"CallerName"];
```

as you have already (realised after I typed ha)

**EDIT 2**

You need to implement `UITableViewDelegate` method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.leads_calls.count;
}
```

To ensure that only the number of cells created in the UITableView matches the count of objects in the array.

If I were you I'd look into creating a model class for your response object too, it will make your life easier later on perhaps.

Comment: The class of response object is: __NSCFArray, which is interesting...Does AFNetworking return an array to me? ...

Comment: And if that's the case, how can I store that array and use it in the UItableView cell.textlabel.text?

Comment: Check my edit, I think I will have cracked it for you. It's all a matter of the data types you have mixed up. To answer your other q: AFNetworking returns a type of id which can be any object that inherits from NSObject, I'm not sure exactly what object class is normally returned. Guess it's different for different response types.

Comment: Thanks for your help...we're on a roll now. I'm having a different issue now...I'm getting this error: [__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]' When I call tableview reload

Comment: You are trying to access an object that isn't in the array (the array has 3 objects and you are trying to access a 4th object) ensure you don't by implementing my updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, I'm already doing that and it's still giving that error. What's really odd is I'm not sure where it's getting the count of 3. It is saying that the index is out of bounds 0..2 at 3. So where does it get the number 3 if I'm requesting 5 and getting 5 results back in my object?

Comment: What's the value of: self.leads_calls.count?

Comment: I just logged it as 5, that is bizarre no?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31359/discussion-between-chris-jenkins-and-adam-waite)

Answer (score 1):

Painful to see, but you have dictionaries in and array in an array:

```
2013-06-06 14:32:11.372 SMP[39846:c07]
(
    (
        {
```

Notice there are 2 round brackets...

So, `leads_dict` isn't really a dictionary, it's an array of dictionaries. Having both `leads_dict` and `leads_calls` seems like overkill, remove one of them. Ensure that the one left is an array and use that to drive your table view.

Comment: Awesome, I fixed that, and now I'm getting an exception on tableview reloadData. The index is beyond bounds and I'm not sure why that's happening

Comment: My index does not go out of bounds if I only request 1 result from my url. I had it set to 5 and it was going 3 over. Any way you know of to fix that? Can I presize my index?